# How to prepare for a Mansions of Madness session efficiently?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I own the core game, and the Forgotten Alchemy and the Call of the Wild expansions. That means a lot of cards.

That also means that before every session, there is a lot of preparation. The worst part is sorting out the necessary Exploration cards. I love the game itself, but this preparation slowly drives me into madness... Well, this might have been the designer's intention in the first place.

Is there a way to organize everything in a way that results in less preparation time?

Comment: I'm with you - I've resorted to setting up prior to the main group arriving. Takes up to 30 minutes. I hate setting up in front of the other players, especially when we have new ones as they tend to want to ask questions which can distract during the set-up, resulting in potentially wrong setup and broken game that you don't realise till much later!

Answer (score 5):

So far, I have found two ways to simplify the preparation:

1. Some exploration cards (and other elements) are only used in a single scenario. I separate all such scenario-specific components, and store each such scenario separated.
2. Storing the exploration card sorted alphabetically greatly decreases the search time.

Comment: This obviously requires longer pack up time as well to keep things sorted

Comment: Obviously. However, the net time gain is substantial.

Comment: You'd be pleased to find out that the second edition rules recommend we sort cards alphabetically =)